# How to fix error [<UIViewController 0x752f5a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I'm new to IOS and I'm stuck with an error I added a table view in my storyboard named timelinetable and after some time I deleted that from my storyboard but after that when debugging it shows an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   timelineTable.'

but I cant find anything named timelinetable in my project so how can I fix that problem

Comment: Have you tried to "Clean" before building?  Certain that you've deleted all references to it?

Comment: you forget to remove IBOutlets from your project. remove that Connections.

Comment: @methai yep I tried Clean And I think I've deleted every reference I can see anything named timelinetable in my .m and.h files

Comment: @DipenPanchasara how ???

Comment: @AlenJoy: You have to delete them from the xib . and recreate them .

Comment: in you viewcontroller rightClick on File's Owner and remove the connection with timelinetable

Comment: @DipenPanchasara but Icant see any connection with timelinetable

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I solved my problem Actually the problem is with my simulator after deleting the project from simulator it runs perfectly any way thanks for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49018534/1090024 I came up with the solution on this post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Go to the xib
2. click on files owner and click on the show connection inspector button (last one ).
3. Check out all the connections . The problem is due to you are referencing the outlet which is no more exist.

Comment: @V-Xtream but its not working for me Even I deleted the xib file in the project and its still showing the same error

Comment: I solved my problem Actually the problem is with my simulator after deleting the project from simulator it runs perfectly any way thanks for the help

Comment: @AlenJoy:nice to here this.

Answer (score 1):

you connect an outlet and you then remove the controller without removing its outlet.